# warning of mysqli_real_escape_string() for this code

Tags: php

**Query:**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["username"]), $db);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["password"]), $db);
    $password = md5($password);

    $sql = "Insert into login(username,password) values('$username','$password');";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    echo"Successful Registration";

    if($result) {
        echo("Successfully updated");       
    }else{
        die ("no database");
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 19
```

Successful Registrationno database

Comment: And why don't you go read the documentation of `mysqli_real_escape_tring` ? Isn't it easier than coming here and asking a question?

Comment: I don't actually see a question here. Just some code and a few warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are in the wrong order, read the documentation again. For example:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["username"]), $db);
```

Should be:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, trim($_POST["username"]));
```

See http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string (the procedural style) for the right parameter order.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 15

Comment: Are you kidding me? That was an example - do the same fix for all your calls. You got the parameters in the wrong order all over your code.

Comment: even after applying it to all i still get this:

Comment: and m not able to add the records cuza that

Comment: Now go and check the type of parameters you pass around. What type is `$db`? Looks like its not the type expected by the functions you call.